# PyGTK: Opening Links in Default Web Browser

Tags: application-development, pygtk

Is there a way to create a Gtk.Button("http://www.google.com"), when clicked will open the system default Web Browser using the label as the URL?

What I could do is...

```
import os
button = Gtk.Button(label="http://www.google.com")
label = button.get_text()
os.system("sensible-browser " + label)
```

The above code does what I need it to do. Is this the correct way about doing this? Or is there a GTK function I should be using instead?

(Disclaimer: I am usually more specific with my questions, I feel like this is really basic and may not even be possible and I have checked the docs. Thank you!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two solutions in one! :)

First, there is a special button widget just for this job: [GtkLinkButton](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkLinkButton.html). You create a GtkLinkButton just like a normal button. Here is a simple example program written with Python and PyGObject. PyGTK should look pretty similar:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk
window = Gtk.Window()
button = Gtk.LinkButton("http://www.google.com", label="google.com")
window.add(button)
window.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

As an alternative, you can directly call the function [gtk_show_uri](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk3-Filesystem-utilities.html#gtk-show-uri).

If you need more sophisticated application launching stuff, take a look at Gio.

Comment: Wow, I was editing my question and you had already posted. Thanks again I'll try gtk_show_uri first. I forgot to mention its a toolbarbutton, but I'll go look and see if a LinkButton exists for the toolbar.

Answer (score 4):

If someone else is coming here to know how to open a URI in the default browser without using a `Gtk.LinkButton`, the answer is using [`Gtk.show_uri_on_window()`](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gtk-3.0/functions.html#Gtk.show_uri_on_window):

```
Gtk.show_uri_on_window(None, "http://www.google.com", Gdk.CURRENT_TIME)
```